# Why hasn't my Galaxy S3 received the 4.3 update?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-kies, ota-update

The title explains it all. I have an year old Galaxy S3 which runs Android 4.1.1 (stock ROM). Yesterday, my friend received the 4.3 update however, I haven't. Samsung Kies says that the latest firmware is already installed.

Why is it so ?

Is this because the phone was purchased in a country different from where I reside currently ?
Also, how do I update to 4.3 if it is a country issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I believe Samsung has suspended the 4.3 update for now.  Have a look [here](http://www.sammobile.com/2013/11/18/samsung-delivers-official-statement-regarding-galaxy-s3s-android-4-3-update-issues/).